# Blogger gadget "This content is not yet available over encrypted connections"

Tags: https, blogger

I have troubles to create a blogger gadget that works with https. Currently I use the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="A Title" />
  <Content type="html">
     <![CDATA[
     <p id="demo"></p>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Page hostname is " + window.location.hostname
     </script>
     ]]>
  </Content>
</Module>
```

When I add this gadget to my blog it shows only:

```
Gadget
This content is not yet available over encrypted connections.
```

I don't see why this should not work with https.
It seems to work in the preview.

Comment: The XML gadgets added via the **Add your own** option don't work with HTTPS connection. It would be better to directly code the gadget using an HTML/JavaScript gadget

Comment: Wow, thanks! I did not thought about that. The Add gadget dialog just says "Some gadgets contributed by third party developers may not be compatible with HTTPS.", but not that any gadget will not work.